# Fastest way to fetch one row per partition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which is partitioned by LIST(id).

```
create table a (
  id serial not null,
  col1 int not null,
  col2 int null,
  col3 <type3>, 
  ...,
  coln <typen>

) partition by list(id);
```

In a given partition, col2 can either all be null or all be not null.
What I wish for is the fastest way to fetch one row with id, col1, col2 per partition.
Right now, the fastest way I have of doing this is:

```
select id, col1, col2 from (select row_number() over (partition a by id) as r,t.id, t.col1, t.col2 from a t) x where x.r =1;
```

However, this still has to do an append +seq scan on each individual partition followed by a sort on id, before it runs a windowAgg and actually runs the filter.

Is there a way to ensure that it only appends one row per partition on the append step itself? Failing that, how would I optimize this query such that the number of rows in each sub-partition don't matter and the query is agnostic of this?

Comment: Please add an `ORDER BY` clause to your call to `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, adding an `ORDER BY` clause makes no difference in performance because it does a quick sort on `id` even without the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Does `id` have an index on it already?

Comment: The table is list partitioned by id. It can't be indexed on `id`

Comment: "Is there a way to ensure that it only appends one row per partition on the append step itself?"  What is being appended to what?  This is a `select` query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff OP is talking about the "Append" node in a PostgreSQL execution plan that implements `UNION` and combination of results from different partitions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that with a single query.

But you can construct a metadata query that will result in a fast query.

I use `psql`'s exec to execute this dynamic query, but you can do it as you please:

```
SELECT string_agg(
          format(
             '(SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM %s LIMIT 1)',
             inhrelid::regclass
          ),
          E'\nUNION ALL\n'
       )
FROM pg_inherits
WHERE inhparent = 'a'::regclass \gexec
```